# invoking bash builtins from tclsh

Tags: bash, tcl, built-in

I have a tclsh script in which I needed to execute certain command in background.
I could achieve this from tcl using exec command: `exec myprog &`.

But how can I wait for `myprog` to complete from tcl.
The command `wait` is not a standalone utility so I can use it with `exec`.
The `wait` command is a shell builtin. Please let me know how can I wait for the background process in tclsh script.

PS: I am using #!/usr/bin/env tclsh shebang in my script.

Comment: @rkosegi: Presumably the command no longer executes in the background.

Comment: If I remove &, the command executes and returns once myprog is completed... so no question of `wait` at all...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to execute a command in the background in Tcl, you could go for something along the line of:

```
proc cb { fd } {
        gets $fd buf
        append ::output $buf
        if {[eof $fd]} {
            close $fd
            set ::finished 1
        }
}

set command "<command to execute>"
set ::output ""
set ::finished 0
set fd [open "|$command" r]
fconfigure $fd -blocking no
fileevent $fd readable "cb $fd"
vwait ::finished
puts $::output
```

The use of `open` with a `|` before the command will allow you to "open" a pipe to the command. Using `fconfigure` to set it non-blocking will allow you to read from it without locking any other process in the script. `fileevent` will call the specified callback proc (in this case `cb`) whenever there's data to be read (thus the `readable` flag). `vwait` will make sure the script does not proceed until the specified variable is written to, thus the `$command` will be executed in the background, allowing say a Tk interface to remain responsive and waiting until you want to continue.

Comment: Nice - but the question seems to be 'how to run the command synchronously' rather than 'asynchronously'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well yes and no? My understanding is that the OP wants the process to execute in the background, but Tcl exits before the command is complete, so the command should be executed asynchronously, but the application should wait for it to finish.